# What kind of energy is stored inside an inductor of an $LC$ circuit?

Tags: electromagnetism, energy-conservation, electromagnetic-induction

As I have learnt, electricity and magnetism are analogous in many ways. In terms of formula, capacitors are also analogous to inductors in a circuit. However, I can visualise electrical energy stored in a capacitor as potential energy (due to the potential difference across), but how do I visualise this so-called “magnetic energy” in the inductor? Is it a form of potential energy too? Some compare it to kinetic energy, which I cannot understand. So what kind of energy conversion undergoes when the inductor induces this emf that opposes the change of current?

Answer (score 2):

The energy in a capacitor is stored in its electric field. Let's do a quick calculation to convince ourselves that this is indeed the case before we move on to the inductor. Suppose we have a capacitor of area $A$ and spacing $d$ then the capacitance is:

$$ C = \frac{\epsilon A}{d} $$

and the voltage across the capacitor is:

$$ V = \frac{Q}{C} = \frac{Qd}{\epsilon A} $$

Then the electric field in the region between the plates is:

$$ E = \frac{V}{d} = \frac{Q}{\epsilon A} $$

Now the energy density, i.e. the energy per unit volume, in an electric field is given by:

$$ \rho = \tfrac12 \epsilon E^2 $$

Since the electric field in our capacitor is constant between the plates the energy in the field is just $\rho$ multiplied by the volume $Ad$, so we get:

$$ \mathrm{energy} = \tfrac12 \epsilon \left(\frac{Q}{\epsilon A}\right)^2 Ad = \tfrac12 Q^2\frac{d}{\epsilon A} = \tfrac12 \frac{Q^2}{C} = \tfrac12 CV^2 $$

You probably derived the energy in a capacitor $\tfrac12 CV^2$ by calculating the work done to charge the capacitor, but as the equations above show this is the same as the energy stored in the electric field between the plates.

And with this the answer to your question is hopefully obvious. The energy stored in an inductor is stored in its associated magnetic field. Just like an electric field a magnetic field has an energy density, but given by the equation:

$$ \rho = \tfrac{1}{2\mu}B^2 $$

Unfortunately the form of the magnetic field is generally more complicated than the electric field in our capacitor and I can't think of a simple example to calculate the energy. However if we integrated $\rho dV$ for the inductor we'd find we reproduced the familiar equation for the energy $\tfrac12 L I^2$.

Comment: I think the simplest example of an inductor (calculation-wise) would be a long solenoid, in which $B = \mu NI/\ell$. Naturally this (and neglecting the field outside the solenoid) is an approximation, but it's akin to neglecting fringe fields in a capacitor. With that the energy is easily calculated as $\pi\mu N^2 I^2r^2/(2\ell)$, where $N$ is the number of turns, $\ell$ is the solenoid length and $r$ is the radius.

Comment: So from the derivation of energy in a capacitor, it could be seen that energy is stored in the form of charge (which sets up a potential difference) and depends on the geometry of the capacitor. However, what exactly is the magnetic field storing? If inductance in analogous to capacitance, how can current be analogous to potential difference? Would it be possible to find a physical meaning behind 1/2LI^2?

Comment: @Physikaholic the energy is stored in the electric field that is created between the charges. This is a bit unintuitive because an electric field is an intangible object so you would be forgiven for wondering how it can store energy, but the field really does store energy. A magnetic field store energy in the same way. It's the field that stores the energy not the charges or current that created it.

Answer (score 2):

Take an *ideal* $LC$ resonator, the charges flow back and forth between the capacitor and the inductor a period of oscillation of $T=\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{LC}}$. While at any instant the charges on the plate is $Q=Cv$ and the flux through the inductor is $\Phi=Li$ the total energy $\frac{1}{2}Li^2 + \frac{1}{2}Cv^2=\frac{1}{2L}\Phi^2 + \frac{1}{2C}Q^2$ does not change.

To make an analogue with a mechanical resonator, $\frac{1}{2}mu^2+\frac{1}{2}kx^2$, ($m$ is mass, $u$ is velocity and $x$ is displacement), it is natural to say that the charges on the plates represent "static", or rather potential energy because the *amount* of charge residing on the plates is what determines the energy. In the inductor the *flowing* current is the one determining the energy and current is charges in motion, so it is a kinetic type of energy whose momentum is represented by the flux and $L$ is analogous to mass that even has an inertia as anybody trying to disconnect a large conductor can painfully observe, if not careful.

The reason why $[\Phi, Q]$ is a better analogy than $[i,v]$ because the analogy for $u=\dot x$ is of course $i=\dot Q$ but in the presence of matter neither function $Q=f_e(v)$ or $\Phi = f_m(i)$ is necessarily linear and both may depend on temperature.

It is easier to see the potential field and field energy for a capacitor from Coulomb's law by building it up from the potential field  $\phi(\mathcal P)$ of a single charge $q(\mathcal P')$: $\quad \phi(\mathcal P) = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{q(\mathcal P')}{r_{\mathcal P\mathcal P'}}$.

A magnetic field is more complicated. There are no magnetic charges, in stead it is generated by *dipoles* (current loops) and its potential field is not a scalar but instead isa vector field. Assuming the simplest case of filamentary currents this vector potential field has the form $\mathbf A(\mathcal P) =  \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\oint \frac {\mathbf i d\ell_{\mathcal P'}}{r_{\mathcal P\mathcal P'}}$ where the integral is taken over the filament.

It takes $\phi(\mathcal P)q(\mathcal P)$ work to move a charge $q$ from infinity to $\mathcal P$ where the potential already is $\phi(\mathcal P)$, and if you add these up you get the total work $\frac{1}{2}\sum_{\mathcal P} \phi(\mathcal P)q(\mathcal P)$. (The factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ is there because $ r_{\mathcal P\mathcal P'}=r_{\mathcal P'\mathcal P}$) This work is exactly equal the energy stored in the field  $W_e=\frac{1}{2}\int_V \epsilon_0 E^2dV$.

If you do the same for the magnetic field generated by a current $\mathbf i$ you get $W_m=\frac{1}{2}\int_V \mu_0 H^2dV = \frac{1}{2}\oint \mathbf A \cdot \mathbf i d\ell $. Note that the flux itself is the contour integral of the vector potential $\Phi = \oint \mathbf A \cdot d\ell$, so the work to establish the current loops is the sum $\frac{1}{2}\oint \Phi \mathbf i d\ell$. This way the flux $\Phi$ is understood as flux of the inductive or magnetic "momentum" through the current loops.